# Is it possible to have a css property that depends on the heights of specific elements?

Tags: html, css

I have an html container element which has children, some of which are of the css class `child-active`.

The container should only be as tall as the largest active child. i.e. I want a container's `max-height` to always be the largest `height` of its children which are of the class `child-active`. (The reason I want this is because it would solve a css transition issue for me).

I want something like:

```
.container {
   max-height: calc(max(/* all the heights of .container > .child-active*/));
}

.child {
   ...
}

.child-active {
   ...
}
```

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="child"> the height of this content is ignored </div>
   <div class="child child-active"> the height of this content sets the height of the container </div>
</div>
```

Is this possible to do? Obviously I anticipate it will involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Does  having the  `.container` element to be `display:flex` not solve the problem?

Otherwise, [container queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries) might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to define the height of the child-active and use that same height as max-height for container, otherwise try playing around with max-height: max-content or max-height: auto or max-height: fit-content;
Or use display: flex, define the heights of child and active child and that should be it.

```css
.container {
   display: flex;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
   height: 20px;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}

.child-active {
   height:40px;
   border: 1px solid green;
   
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="child"> the height of this content is ignored </div>
   <div class="child child-active"> the height of this content sets the height of the container </div>
</div>
```